# iPhone development

Tags: iphone

I've a great interest on iPhone Development and How i can start iPhone development ?

I've no basic deals with C but I've programming knowledge and concepts.

Comment: You have tagged your question as `web-development`, do you mean developing websites designed for iphone, or creating apps to be sold on appstore?

Comment: I mean "creating apps to be sold on appstore".

Answer (score 2):

[iPhone Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action) is your starting point. You can try to go through [this](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html) tutorial. Also [this](http://www.daleisphere.com/iphone-app-development-where-to-start/) blog post can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The following three books were instrumental in helping me learning Objective C and iPhone programming quickly.

The essential two Objective C books.

- [http://www.amazon.com/Learn-Objective-ndash-Mac/dp/1430218150/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1283943281&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430218150)
- [http://www.amazon.com/Programming-Objective-C-2-0-Stephen-Kochan/dp/0321566157/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1283943302&sr=8-3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321566157)

Apress iPhone book

- [http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-iPhone-Development-Exploring-SDK/dp/1430224592/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1283943414&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430224592)