# iPhone development - what do i need to get started?

Tags: c#, iphone

I'm looking to start developing an iPhone app. I have zero experience in objective C but have expeirence in C#. I'm just wondering what do I need to develop an iPhone app? Where do i start? What is the best tool to develop in? Do I need a Mac to develop the app or can I do it on a PC with a low amount of pain?

many thanks!

Comment: See similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294214/want-to-start-iphone-development, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332039/getting-started-with-iphone-development, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351825/iphone-development, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885198/beginning-iphone-development, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939/how-to-articles-for-iphone-development-objective-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557543/how-to-start-programming-for-the-iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have a Mac if you wish to put your app on the iTunes App store.

You should get the WWDC 2010 videos (available when you have a developer account on developer.apple.com, and also get the free books from apple in the iBooks store (search apple developer).

So far for me the best tool has been Xcode.

Apple has some excellent getting started videos and Aaron Hillegas has a great book that serves as an introduction to cocoa programming on the mac. (Mac based, but translates well to iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code in c# you should consider [MonoTouch](http://monotouch.net)

Basic Requirements:

- Apple's iPhone SDK 3.2 or higher, available from Apple's iPhone Dev Center (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/).
- An Intel Mac computer running MacOS 10.5 or 10.6 (Leopard or Snow Leopard).
- The latest release of Mono for OSX

Answer (score 0):

Please search this site for `iphone getting started` to get tons of info about this subject (it's a frequently asked question).

And yes, you will need a Mac. If you can't afford a MacBook or iMac, the best solution is to buy a used Mac Mini on eBay or something. No, there really is no way to be able to do iPhone development without a Mac (also a frequently asked question :-).